# Matlab in Ubuntu: Why can't results store into file using 'system'?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-20.04

Matlab R2020b in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:
I plan to use Matlab 'system()' to run Ubuntu. The command is as follows:

```
system('./uvspec < INPUT.txt > OUTPUT.txt');
```

`uvspec` is an executable file. I had prepared the INPUT.txt and wanted results into the OUTPUT. But the OUTPUT can be created and have no data. While I directly run `./uvspec < INPUT.txt > OUTPUT.txt` in ubuntu termimal. It works. I don't know what happened. Is there someone help me? Thanks sincerely.

Comment: Hi Enguang, welcome to SO! What do you get if you run `[status,result] = system('echo 123 >>OUTPUT.txt')` ?

Comment: Try not redirecting stdout to file, but directly grab it in MATLAB. `system` captures stdout in a string in the 2nd output argument. Redirecting input might also not work, not sure.

Comment: @Vicky Hi Vicky, it works. There has '123' in OUTPUT.txt.

Comment: @Vicky And the variable 'status, result' is 0 and 0x0, respectively. But my source code's status showed 127.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hi Cris Luengo, It can show in terminal if I not redirecting stdout to file. But in matlab, the status shows 127. The result shows './uvspec: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.25:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'. Although this error happened, I still can run this code in terminal. It is confusing to me that I had realized this project in Matlab which is running with 30 preceedings.

Comment: Is there a problem with the input file? `[a,b]=system('cat - <INPUT.txt')` Or perhaps with the current working directory / binary file? `c=pwd(),d=ls('-la')`

Comment: Never mind what I just said, your problem seems to be with system libraries then. What do you get with `[a,b]=system('ldd ./uvspec')`, anything else missing?

Comment: @Vicky Yes, there are two libraries missing, 'libnetcdf.so.13' and 'libgsl.so.25'. Is this problem in matlab not in ubuntu?

Comment: @Vicky I don't know why there is not missing with just what I mentioned two libraries when I run 'ldd ./uvspec' in Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Do you know where these two libraries are located? You can check that with e.g. `whereis libgsl.so` (from the terminal). Then try running this from within MATLAB: `[a,b]=system('LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libgsl.so:/usr/lib64/libnetcdf.so ldd ./uvspec')` (make sure to substitute the correct paths). What do you get?

Comment: @Vicky I got more missing libraries, such as liblber-2.4.so. and ```whereis liblber-2.4.so``` doesn't work (just shows ```liblber-2.4:```). Besides, I found the path of all the missing libraries is ``` usr/local/Polyspace/R2020b/bin/glnxa64``` which is different with location ```/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ ``` or ```/usr/local/Myname/lib/``` in terminal. Do I need to change some settings?

Comment: @Vicky I found I don't use ``` sudo ``` to run Matlab, this problem is solved. I don't know the real means of 'sudo'. I just thought it can promote authority for writing file.

Comment: The `bin/glnxa64` folder is where MATLAB keeps its own copies of certain libraries also installed on a system-wide level. You probably don't need to worry right now about anything other than those libraries explicitly listed as "not found" by ldd. To simplify things, try a blanket override of the MATLAB environment by running: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/Myname/lib:<other_relevant_paths_here> ldd ./uvspec` . This will tell the dynamic linker to look for the necessary shared libraries even in funny places MATLAB might not know about. (For details, see `man ld-linux.so`.)

Comment: `sudo` is used to run commands as the root user (as long as you are a sudoer, etc., but these are details), which is generally a security risk when applied to huge programs like MATLAB. I won't bother you with the details, you can look this stuff up online, but it's considered bad, very bad practice. I have a feeling the library problem was nearly solved the way we were heading, which would be a more recommended approach, but it's your computer of course ;)

Comment: @Vicky Thank you very much. OK, I will take care about the ``` LD_LIBRARY_PATH ``` which seems it exists with each software in Linux system, not just for Matlab. I knew little about ubuntu. I will use ``` sudo ``` carefully since hear your advice. Thanks again.

Comment: It seems to me that `system('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Myname/lib/ ./uvspec < INPUT.txt > OUTPUT.txt');` should allow your program to run. MATLAB usually preserves the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it seems that in your case it doesn't. Or maybe you start MATLAB from a menu rather than the command line?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I started Matlab in command line, but with ```sudo```, that may cause some changes for ```LD_LIBRARY_PATH```. Now it works when I don't use 'sudo'. Thanks.

Comment: @Vicky Help, Vicky. Another new question that similar to this problem. ```./sbdart < INPUT ``` ,it came error when I create file 'INPUT' in Matlab. Especially, the first character is ```&```. And then, I input this character again by keyboard and run this code. It works...I don't know why..Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, the first character is `&` ? Is there an ampersand right at the beginning of the filename? BTW: I don't think here is the best place to raise a new question. Why not create a new SO question, showing the MATLAB commands you run and the output (error) you get? (If you can make the question useful to future visitors, all the better; see e.g. stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and the Help Center.)

Comment: @Vicky OK, thanks. I will post a new question and show the detailed pictures.